# Usage of SHAP explainer

Tags: shap

In the following page:

[Shap documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/explainers/Exact.html)

The code contains the following lines:

```
explainer = shap.explainers.Exact(model.predict_proba, X)
shap_values = explainer(X[:100])
```

I'm confused about this usage. What are the purposes of the parameter X (the data) in the first line and the parameter the X[:100] in the second line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is used as background data, while `X[:100]` are the 100 observations to be explained.